# CRC-32 for STM32L4 calculate from HAL_CRC_Calculate(); function

Tags: stm32, crc

As CRC Configuration below

```
      hcrc.Instance = CRC;
      hcrc.Init.DefaultPolynomialUse = DEFAULT_POLYNOMIAL_ENABLE;
      hcrc.Init.DefaultInitValueUse = DEFAULT_INIT_VALUE_ENABLE;
      hcrc.Init.InputDataInversionMode = CRC_INPUTDATA_INVERSION_NONE;
      hcrc.Init.OutputDataInversionMode = CRC_OUTPUTDATA_INVERSION_DISABLE;<br>
      hcrc.InputDataFormat = CRC_INPUTDATA_FORMAT_BYTES;
      if (HAL_CRC_Init(&hcrc) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
```

Polynomial state : `default (MPEG-2 : 0x04C11DB7)`
Value stage : `default (MPEG-2 : 0xFFFFFFFF)`
The result data calculate from HAL_CRC_Calculate(...); is `0xD2AEA5A1`

```
      uint32_t data[2]={0x01, 0x01};
      uint32_t crc_cal;
      crc_cal = HAL_CRC_Calculate(&hcrc, data, 2);
      sprintf(VariableDebug,"CRC Value (HAL_CRC Cal.) %08X, ",crc_cal);
      PRINT_MSG_CYAN(VariableDebug);
```

It's not the same as data from CRC online is `0xD66FB816` as Link below
https://crccalc.com/
Could you please help me solve this problem?

Best regards,
Suchada Sri.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change this:

```
uint32_t data[2]={0x01, 0x01};
uint32_t crc_cal;
crc_cal = HAL_CRC_Calculate(&hcrc, data, 2);
```

To this:

```
uint8_t data[]={0x01, 0x01};
uint32_t crc_cal;
crc_cal = HAL_CRC_Calculate(&hcrc, (uint32_t*)data, 2);
```

For good practice, you can also use `sizeof(data)` instead of `2`.

Comment: This is wrong and will cause undefined behavior. It tells `HAL_CRC_Calculate` that there are 2 `uint32_t`s when in fact there is only half an `uint32_t`. Do not use this!